Issue with WalletButton for Gate.io in RainbowKit
I'm experiencing an issue with the WalletButton component from the RainbowKit library. Specifically, I'm trying to pass the Gate.io wallet, but it results in a connector error.
import { WalletButton } from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit';


Uncaught runtime errors: × ERROR Connector not found at WalletButtonRenderer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:514033:11) at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278692:22) at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:282259:24) at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:283978:20) at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:268948:18) at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:268992:20) at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:269049:35) at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:288947:11) at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:288195:16) at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:288118:9)

